# Did any of the Avengers serve as Heralds of Galactus?

Tags: marvel, comics, avengers, galactus

**[The Heralds of Galactus](http://marvel.com/universe/Heralds_of_Galactus#axzz5Bz79vhAE)** were individuals who were imbued with a fraction of the power cosmic by Galactus himself. Some well known heralds include the [Silver Surfer](http://marvel.com/universe/Silver_Surfer) (Norrin Radd of Zenn-La), [Terrax the Tamer](http://marvel.com/universe/Terrax), [Nova](https://marvel.com/universe/Nova_(Frankie_Raye)) (Frankie Raye) and many others (listed [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Heralds_of_Galactus_(Earth-616))).

In the animated series ***Avengers Assemble Season 2 Episode 25: New Frontiers***, Iron Man briefly served as the herald before leading Galactus to a trap (I won't reveal details about the episode's plot). This got me thinking.

Was there, at any point in time (in the comics), an Avenger who was turned into a herald (*voluntarily or otherwise*)?

Comment: Depends on what level of 'canon' you want.  In Marvel Zombies, several Avengers *ate* the Silver Surfer, gained the Power Cosmic, then proceeded to kill, eat, and ***replace*** Galactus as the world-devourer.  I don't think they were ever technically heralds though.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is to define how do you qualify "being an Avenger", 'cause there have been plenty of different groups with that name over the years. There have been parallel, official branches of the "main" Avenger team, unofficial ones, new ones (when the original was shut down), and every kind of variations on the theme you can think about.

That said, luckily the list of known Galactus' heralds is quite short:

- Tyrant
- Fallen One
- Silver Surfer
- Air-Walker
- Firelord
- Destroyer
- Terrax the Tamer
- Nova
- Morg the Executioner
- Red Shift
- Human Torch
- Stardust
- Praeter
- Anti-Man

Of those, the only one who could be considered an Avenger is the Human Torch: he has been part of **Secret Avengers** (during Civil Wars) and of **Avengers Unity Squad**.

So yes, we have an Avenger who has been an herald of Galactus, too.

But, coming to your question as stated:

> Was there, at any point in time (in the comics), an Avenger who was
>   turned into a herald (voluntarily or otherwise)?

then the answer is no: what we have is a Galactus' (unwilling) herald who later become an Avenger.

Comment: Well yeah. I too concluded the same. Here's the details to add in your answer. http://marvel.com/universe/Human_Torch_(Johnny_Storm)#Herald_of_Galactus

Answer (score 0):

Not really an Avenger, but Deadpool briefly become the herald after answering an ad for it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thu1X.jpg

(sorry don't know if I can embed albums.

Comment: Deadpool's surf board is bad-ass.. :)

Comment: You can't embed albums, but you can embed single images.

Comment: *"Not really an Avenger"*, so why offer him as an answer on a question specifically asking about Avengers?

Comment: Again, just as Johnny Storm was a member of the Avengers Unity Squad (i.e., Uncanny Avengers), so was Deadpool. And Steve Rogers recruited him *before* being cosmic cube-d into a Hydra agent. Now, if you want to argue if the Deadpool story itself was "real", you might be able to get some traction; I have a great deal of difficulty thinking Galactus would place a classified ad in an Earth newspaper to find a new herald.

Answer (score 0):

Dazzler: "Unable to cope with her "murder," Dazzler used the energy to free herself from the confines on PEGASUS. The strong energy signature alerted the space entity Galactus to the young mutant, who abducted her as a means of retrieving his renegade herald, Terrax. Galactus then imbued Dazzler with the power cosmic -- a source of unlimited sound energy, allowing the human to enter a black hole to retrieve the herald. Dazzler succeeded in her task and, using her virtue of compassion, convinced Galactus to pardon Terrax and return her to Earth." and Human Torch

Comment: Dazzler was *never* an Avenger. Nevertheless, Human torch was a part of the Secret Avengers (so that is a valid response). But you could provide some sources to improve your answer and make it acceptable.

Comment: @Shreedhar She was an Avenger the same way Johnny Storm was, simply by being a member of one of the many branches of the group. Point is, this answer is totally off target 'cause Dazzler has never been an herald of Galactus. With all the offsprings the main Avenger group had it's way complicated to say who is and who's not, but when it comes to Galactus' heralds the list is quite short and clear.

Comment: @motoDrizzt I searched online but couldn't find any source linking Dazzler as an Avenger (or any avenger version). That's why.

Comment: @motoDrizzt - Which branch of the Avengers was Dazzler a member of? I also cannot think of one. She's been in multiple iterations of the X-Men (The Uncanny team from roughly the Mutant Massacre through the Siege Perilous, plus "New Excalibur" (with Juggernaut), the "X-TREME X-MEN" variant that was more like the Exiles, and interacting with the Uncanny team again in the run between AvX and Secret Wars (at which point she was also briefly an agent of S.H.I.E.L.D.)

Comment: Well, I could be wrong. She was in A-Force, which initially was a parallel universe Avenger main team, but then integrated in the main Marvel universe after Secrete Wars. She could be an Avenger, from my point of view, but this is quite borderline. But as I said is the same for Johnny Storm: he was in two groups of Avengers-maybe, so it's a complicated call.